# How to change payment method from WooCommerce order confirmation email to payment source

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-email

We are using Woocommerce Payments and on our order confirmation email the payment method comes up as Woocommerce Payments instead of the payment source such as Visa, Mastercard etc.

[image]

I have found how to remove the Payment method altogether (see below), but how would I remove this and add back in Payment Source?

```
<tfoot>
<?php
    if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ( $totals as $key => $total ) {
            $i++;
            if ( $key !== 'payment_method' ){
                ?><tr>
                    <th scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                    <td style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                </tr><?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't think there's a hook to change the payment source or to add something into the table.  But there are hooks that would allow you to insert information before or after the table.  This [visual guide](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/) may be helpful.

Comment: This is so helpful Dave! Thank you.

Comment: @MarneyFontana There does exist a hook to add/remove something to/from the table without having to overwrite the template file. 
My question here is, isn't it more a matter of modifying the existing row instead of deleting it and add a new one? 
Which plugin is it specifically about? since there are many plugins with similar names

Comment: @7uc1f3r yes I would much prefer to modify the existing row. It is not a plug-in, just the default woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php template that I am hoping to modify. The confusion comes from when a customer sees the Order Confirmation screen after they have made a purchase, the Payment Method is started correctly as "Visa credit card", but on the email the customer receives, the Payment Method now displays Woocommerce Payments (as per screenshot above)

Comment: @MarneyFontana You can overwrite the value (as in the answer given to your question), but i believe it's better to look at where the value comes from instead of using a 'workaround'. To get that value `get_payment_method_title()` is used in WooCommerce, and this can simply be adjusted via the WooCommerce settings. 
Have you already viewed/adjusted that setting? 
It can be found via WooCommerce -> Settings -> Payments (or checkout) -> Manage 
the desired method -> Title

Answer (score 1):

In your functions.php add this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'change_payment_method_name_in_emails', 10, 3 );
function change_payment_method_name_in_emails( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    // On Email notifications only
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        if($total_rows['payment_method']['value'] === 'Woocommerce Payments'){
            $total_rows['payment_method']['value'] = 'Visa/Master';
        }
    }
    return $total_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the order field `_payment_method_title` is used in emails, while `'_payment_method` is the one displayed in the admin panel. So one option would be to update this field:

```
$order->update_meta_data('_payment_method_title', '(payment method');
```

You could do this in an action when the order is created or marked paid.